# Meaning "scheming for the masses" in song the Thunder?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "scheming" in the Imagine Dragons' song "Thunder"? The song is about the singer whose dreams about being a musical celebrity have been oppressed in his childhood.

I would guess "scheming for the masses" means in the context something like "I was planning big concerts" or "I was being formed to be a rock star" but I'm not really sure.

> Kids were laughing in my classes
>
> While I was scheming for the masses
>
> Who do you think you are?
>
> Dreaming 'bout being a big star

Comment: A different approach to the word *scheming* is [here](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/scheming); it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His usage probably means

> scheming for the masses
>   ***planning/plotting on capturing*** *the masses*

since he wanted to be  rock star